# Extending User model with one to one field- how to set user instance in view

Tags: django

I am trying to extend the user model using a one to one relationship to a UserProfile model. I added some boolean fields and in the view I am trying to use those fields as permissions.

Here is my model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ProximityAccess = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    NewProxAccess = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and here is the view I am trying to use:

```
@login_required
def NewProx(request):
    if UserProfile.NewProxAccess:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProxForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                ProxPart_instance = form.save(commit=True)
                ProxPart_instance.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/proximity')
        else:
            form = ProxForm()
            return render(request, 'app/NewProx.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

I don't get any error messages but it does not work as intended. I was hoping that if the user profile had NewProxAccess set to False it would raise the PermissionDenied but it doesn't. I have the admin module wired up and I can select or deselect the checkbox for that field but it has no effect. If I comment out the rest I can get it to show the Permission Denied error so it has to be in the view (I think). I think I am missing a line the establishes the logged in user as the user instance so we can check to see if the user has the permission or not. I know there are a ton of ways to do this and there is probably a better way but for the sake of learning, what is it that I am missing for this to work?

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to check access for particular profile but not `UserProfile` model you need to do:

```
   if request.user.userprofile.NewProxAccess:
        # your code
```

As a note: according to PEP8 best practices you should use camelCase only for naming Classes. For attrs, functions use underscore: my_function

Comment: Awesome thanks so much. I never would have thought to change the case. I will read up on the PEP8.